# How to reset autonumber if the day changes in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access

I have created autonumber in a textbox (TxtNumb.Text) where if the database is empty it will display REG01 and if there is any content then the textbox will display REG02, REG03, and so on.

In the program there is a textbox to display the date with the format `TxtDate.Text = Date.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy")`. The question is how to reset autonumber if the day changes (textbox becomes REG01 again)?

Previously I had made it but it didn't work if for the next day, here is the code that I created:

```
Sub AutoNumb()
    Call Connection() `This section is for connecting to the MS.Access DB`
    dbCommand = New OleDbCommand("select Kd_Testing from tblTesting order by Kd_Testing desc", dbConn)
    dataReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader
    dataReader.Read()
    If Not dataReader.HasRows Then
        TxtNumb.Text = "REG01"
    Else
        TxtNumb.Text = "REG" + Format(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(dataReader("Kd_Testing"), 2) + 1, "00")
    End If
End Sub
```

Previously, thank you for answering.

#Edit, Addition

I want to create a program by saving to the database like the example below, the code I created above can only autonumber it, such as: REG01, REG02, ..., REG05, and so on.

```
|Kd_Testing|Name_Testing        |Date_Testing|
|REG01     |Testing 01, day 20th|20 Aug 2020 |
|REG02     |Testing 02, day 20th|20 Aug 2020 |
|REG01     |Testing 01, day 21th|21 Aug 2020 |
|...       |...                 |...         |
|REG10     |Testing 10, day 21th|21 Aug 2020 |
|REG01     |Testing 01, day 22th|22 Aug 2020 |
```

Then during REG99, the program will get an error, therefore I want to make it if the day changes then Kd_Testing starts again to REG01.

Comment: Please post the schema for tblTesting.

Comment: Thank you for answering it. The following is the schematic table of tblTesting:
Kd_Testing (Short Text (5)), Name_Testing (Short Text (20)), and Date_Testing (Short Text (20)).

Comment: here `dataReader.Read()     If Not dataReader.HasRows Then` do this: `If dataReader.Read() Then ..... Else ....`

Comment: Is this a multi user environment? Does more than one person use this database?

Comment: What is the primary key of the tblTesting table?

Comment: What are you going to do after the numbers are greater than 99?

Comment: Why would you have Date_Testing as a text field? It should be a Date field!

Answer (score 0):

Modify your SQL to retrieve only records where the date is today, like so.

```
Sub AutoNumb()
    Call Connection() *This section is for connecting to the MS.Access DB*
    dbCommand = New OleDbCommand("select Kd_Testing from tblTesting where Date_Testing='" & Date.Now.ToString() & "' order by Kd_Testing desc", dbConn)
    dataReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader
    dataReader.Read()
    If Not dataReader.HasRows Then
        TxtNumb.Text = "REG01"
    Else
        TxtNumb.Text = "REG" + Format(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(dataReader("Kd_Testing"), 2) + 1, "00")
    End If
End Sub
```

You may need to adjust the Date.Now to get the proper format for how you are storing the dates in `Date_Testing`.

Answer (score 0):

Keep you connections local to the method where they are used.
The Call keyword is normally not necessary in vb.net.
Connections need to be closed and diposed. Commands need to be disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks handle this for you even it there is an error.

I added a Where clause to your Select statement with a parameter for today's date.

Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

You will see that you may have problems with datatypes. I showed how to use .net methods rather than the old vb6 methods. I also showed how to use an interpolated string which is available in Visual Studio 2015 forward.

```
Sub AutoNumb()
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string"),
            dbCommand As New OleDbCommand("select Kd_Testing from tblTesting Where Date_Testing = @Date order by Kd_Testing desc", cn)
        dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@Date", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy")
        cn.Open()
        Using dataReader As OleDbDataReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader
            If Not dataReader.HasRows Then
                TxtNumb.Text = "REG01"
            Else
                dataReader.Read()
                Dim firstRecord = dataReader.GetString(0)
                Dim last2Characters = firstRecord.Substring(firstRecord.Length - 2)
                TxtNumb.Text = $"REG{CInt(last2Characters) + 1:00}"
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Rolling your own auto number is a bad idea. Databases are very good at assigning a unique number to a record. Let them do it.